# Column from SQL Table to Int List C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, xamarin

So, I have a class

```
public class Glukoza {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create a List and put into it Value of every element of databse. How to do that?

I tried this, but It doesn't work.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
var norma = _connection.QueryAsync<Glukoza>("SELECT Value FROM Glukoza", list).Result.ToList();
```

Comment: you should virtually *never* use `.Result` - that should just be `var norma = await _connection.QueryAsync(...);`. Now: what does "it doesn't work" mean? what happens **exactly**? and: what is `list`? what does it mean to you?

Comment: @MarcGravell I used .Result because I can't use .ToList() method without it. I got an unhandled exception, it's a Xamarin project.

Comment: well, yeah, you need to `await` before you can `.ToList()`: `var norma = (await _connection.QueryAsync<Glukoza>(...)).ToList();`

Comment: I still have a unhandled exception. :/

Comment: And you still haven't told us *what the exception says*. We're not psychic. You need to actually tell us what it says.

Comment: Ok, so I created a new async method
async public void Baza()
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            var norma = (await _connection.QueryAsync<int>("SELECT Value FROM Glukoza", list)).ToList();
            listaa.ItemsSource = list;
        }
And error says: An unhandled exception occured.: wystąpił wyjątek(translation: exception occured)

Answer (score 1):

Since `Value` is `int`, you should be using `int` as `QueryAsync`'s type argument:

```
var norma = (
    await _connection.QueryAsync<int>("SELECT Value FROM Glukoza", list)
    .ConfigureAwait(false)
).ToList();
```

Since this is an asyncronous call, the method from which you make it needs to be `async`.

Comment: If they are trying to read all 3 columns, `QueryAsync<Glukoza>` was fine

Comment: @MarcGravell It looks like OP projects only values in his SQL, though, so I figured he probably wants an `int`.

Comment: hmm; yes, you're right; I guess it needs clarification from the OP!